# Build a database in the cloud

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, cloud

This is going to be a super newbie question and I've searched but just didn't find an adequate answer. So here's what I'm looking for:

I'm looking for a cheap to free way to create a SQL database in the cloud. Basically, I should be able to go on the browser, log in to an admin panel and create new fields etc and populate them. Then I would like to be able to populate the database via a REST call to another database that responds in JSON format and sends the data over.

Additionally, when I make the call to retrieve the contents from another server, I need to have some logic to modify the data. My expertise is in Java so I'm really just looking for a cloud based solution where I can write some code in Java to grab data from another server and populate my own database with it that I created in the cloud as well.

I suspect there are a million ways to do this so if you could just give me an idea of the most basic one to get started, that'll be great!

Thanks,

-Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Check out Amazon Web Services... you can launch a micro instance server for free and play around with it.

Comment: How would I create a MySQL database though and the tables, fields etc?

Comment: Well it has to 'live' in the cloud somewhere.. so AWS 'could' be that home, there are plenty of help and setup guides for both AWS ec2 servers and mySQL on Amazon's site.

Comment: OK I signed up for AWS and created a mySQL DB instance. I guess my question is how do I operate on the DB within AWS. That is, create a table, fields, field types, etc. I would like to be able to visually see the database and it's contents

Comment: Search for how to access phpMyAdmin.. It's a web based interface for administrating a mySQL db

Answer (score 0):

im not really sure in what solution you Are exactly looking for but have you thought about using a simple mysql Cluster?

You can configure mysql to sybchronize with One or more databases automatically. 
When you setup a simple apache + mysql + phomyadmin Stack this pretty easy to do. 
Then additionally you can put a loadbalancer in Front or connect your Applications roundtable-robbin to Differenz databases.